# Validation of two different xpaths in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two xpaths two validate and increase the count of two different xpaths during run time.

xpath1 and xpath2 - These two xpahts are from calendar view. I have scenario to validate xpath1 is available on 1 and 2 date in calendar. Then xpath2 is on 3 and 4th day of calendar. Like this xpath is again on 5th and 6th day.. then xpath2 is on 7th and 8th day of calendar view...Like this this xpaths continues for complete one month.

I got stuck to validate xpath1 and xpath2 on calendar view for given one month. I took two xpaths and when it validate xpath1 on 3rd day , then it is coming out from the loop and getting failed with error message as 'element not found'.

Kindly help me on this validation part with selenium java code.

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Try to create a dynamic x-path based on date or post the html view here.